# datetimepicker is not a function jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I working with datetimepicker jquery ui, when code below html , datetimepicker is not displaying and when i inspect with `firebug console` it displayed an error ``

```
$("#example1").datetimepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error] $("#example1").datetimepicker();
```

and below is the code

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>
    .ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }

    .ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
    .ui-timepicker-div dl dt { height: 25px; margin-bottom: -25px; }
    .ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 65px; }          
    .ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }           
    .ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }                   

</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#example1").datetimepicker();
    });
</script>

<script>

</script>

<input type="text" id="example1" class="hasDatePicker">
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?  Also, what's the purpose of the    jquery-ui.datepicker.js file?  The jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js should already contain all jQuery widgets, including the datepicker

Comment: Maybe [this][1] question/answers can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function

Comment: @Dirk  jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1, and i have removed all scripts except the jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js , but then i gives and error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Keep in mind, the jQuery UI's datepicker is not initialized with datetimepicker(), there appears to be a plugin/addon here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/.

However, with just jquery-ui it's actually initialized as `$("#example").datepicker()`.  See jQuery's demo site here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#example1").datepicker();
    });
```

To use the datetimepicker at the link referenced above, you will want to be certain that your scripts path is correct for the plugin.

Comment: How would I use this, it just returns a random string which does not relate to the date as far as I can see.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem with bootstrap datetimepicker extension. Including moment.js before datetimepicker.js was the solution.

Answer (score 13):

For some reason this link solved my problem...I don't know why tho..

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Then this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

NOTE: I am using **Bootstrap 3** and **Jquery 1.11.3**

Answer (score 11):

It's all about the order of the scripts.
Try to reorder them, place jquery.datetimepicker.js to be last of all scripts!

Answer (score 3):

```
Place your scripts in this order:   

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example1").datetimepicker({
      allowMultidate: true,
      multidateSeparator: ','
    });
 });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.