# Trent Richardson Datetime Picker doesn't work extended function .datetimepicker()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I think my problem is simple and perhaps not directly related to the component of Richardson.

**TypeError: $ (...). DateTimePicker is not a function**

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bassvix/NUA6v/

Was added all the references of the Richardson´s sample page but still does not work.
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ # basic_examples

Copied the source code from one example.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input class="hasDatepicker" name="slider_example_4" id="slider_example_4" value="" type="text">
</div>
```

**Scripts: (console.log for display finded control)**

```
console.log ($ ('# slider_example_4'));

$ ('# slider_example_4'). datetimepicker({
controlType: 'select',
timeFormat: 'hh: mm tt'
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not add: `class="hasDatepicker"` to the input. This is done by the datetimepicker JavaScript itself.

Your fiddle doesn't work because you cannot pull the JS and CSS files from trentrichardson.com remotely.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/2Kp56/1/

Comment: I have to test before using and not using class="hasDatepicker" and doesn´t.

I have to do other test using only:

    <input type="text" name="eventDateTime" id="datetimepicker" />

And

        $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker(
            {
                controlType: 'select',
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
            }
        );

And works, but when using in my project doesnt work.

In some test I found a direction of the problem, some conflict with Globalize and Wijmo.

Comment: In some tests I found a direction of the problem, some conflict with Globalize and Wijmo.
Also find this post, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678254/datetimepicker-is-not-a-function-jquery) confirm my suspicion. 

But not works yet.