# TempusDominus v4 not a function

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, bootstrap-4, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am trying to use Tempus Dominus with Bootstrap 4 and AngularJS.

[GitHub](https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4)  [Docs/Usage](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/)

Sadly, I can't get it to work, I get an error.

I have the following code:

```
var picker = $('#datetimepicker1'); // I tried this
var picker = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#datetimepicker1' ) ); // And this
picker.datetimepicker();
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: picker.datetimepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (eventDetailController.js:15)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

### Require

I am using RequireJS and this is my shim loader part for datetimepicker:

```
'datetimepicker': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'moment-wrapper', 'moment']
 }
```

### More Information

I am using NPM and Bower (no Webpack).

- Bootstrap: v4.0.0-alpha.6
- jQuery: latest

Comment: I would start from the config. How did you install the Bootstrap? Do you use webpack?

Comment: @proti I have added some informations that you could find useful

Comment: OK, Cool. But how you require Bootstrap to the project? Are you able to use any Bootstrap and jQuery components or classes? 
look here maybe it will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678254/datetimepicker-is-not-a-function-jquery

Comment: @proti yes, Bootstrap and jQuery are working correctly. I have solved the problem with an other datepicker now.