# JQuery.load breaks other javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use JQuery.load, it breaks my other JavaScript libraries. I receive this error:

```
TypeError: $.doTimeout is not a function
```

When I do not use jQuery.load it, works fine.

I don't understand causes this to happen. Seems like it couldn't find the function from the JavaScript file that is already rendered on source code.

Scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery.ba-dotimeout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/test1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/test2.js"></script>
```

Inside test1.js

```
$.doTimeout("hoverOut");
```

Inside test2.js

```
$(".test").load("/test.aspx?param=" + someValue);
```

jquery.ba-dotimeout.js is a library

test1.js uses that library to do its fancy stuff

Please help

Comment: my guess is test.aspx is including a 2nd jquery library that is overriding the first.

Comment: You are right. Thanks! If you had clicked the "answer question" button, I can put it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you include test.aspx, another copy of jQuery.js is being included which overrides the existing version, thus causing the plugins to be lost (they were on the previous version, but not on the one that was added by test.aspx).

Either remove jquery.js from test.asmx, or add a selector to the .load to filter the results.

```
$(".test").load("/test.aspx?param=" + someValue + " #targetdivtoload");
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very similar to the one which I struggled for a week.(Now I got rid of it :) )
[jQuery UI " $("#datepicker").datepicker is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function)

Actually, if you are including 2 .js library., you must be sure that., they does not contain definitions for same function.

> I don't understand causes this to happen. Seems like it couldn't find
>   the function from the JavaScript file that is already rendered on
>   source code.

Overriding., also could cause the same problem.