# I want to display/calculate week number by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just few days old in javascript and jquery.my question is first select date from date picker or calendar and easily convert this date into week number. Please help me because i don't know anything about that..plzzzzz

Comment: @AnoopJoshi like, 47, 52 week of the year, Nilesh More cant you google it a little bit, i think you will be able to find something out there.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/3785/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: @Anup-Week number means 1 to 53 depending on selected date

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquerys date picker try the following

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="calendar">
```

**JS**

```
 $(".calendar").datepicker({
        showWeek: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert("Week " + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
        }
    });
```

[Heres the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q26bccxw/)

Comment: hello sir, i used your code for my project but I run individual program it worked excellent. but when I merged it with my KPI tracking Tool project then it doesnt work,it gives  "Uncaught typeError: $(...) datepicker is not function." please help me. My code is below, 
$(".calendar").datepicker({      
    altField       : "#alternate1",
    altFormat      : "DD, d MM, yy", 
   onSelect: function(dateText) 
    {  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  $("#alternate").val(+date.getFullYear());  
  $(this).val("week number"+ $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));  
    } 
});

Comment: @NileshMore See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get the week from the given date.
http://jsfiddle.net/3TA4s/134/

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="date1" id="startdate">
<input type="text" placeholder="date2" id="enddate">
<input type="text" id="days">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#startdate,#enddate" ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
firstDay: 1,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
})

$( "#startdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
$( "#enddate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

$('#enddate').change(function() {
    var start = $('#startdate').datepicker('getDate');
    var end   = $('#enddate').datepicker('getDate');

if (start<end) {
    var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24/7;
$('#days').val(parseInt(days));
}
else {
  alert ("You cant come back before you have been!");
  $('#startdate').val("");
  $('#enddate').val("");
    $('#days').val("");
}
}); //end change function
}); //end ready
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you setting `dateFormat` twice?

Comment: I didnt notice that. Just sont want to use for the two times. Thanks @Cobote