# How to include datepicker in Django modelform?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, datepicker

I have already seen all the questions about this topic but i couldnt solve my problem, my error is: "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function"

Here is my code:

**html**

```
.....

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
</script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap/css/jquery-ui.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap/css/estilo.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/bootstrap/js/jquery-ui.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>

<div class="form-group">

    <label for="nacimiento" class="control-label col-md-2">Nacimiento:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="nacimiento" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>

....
```

In the html code i have all the form and every thing that let the page run... i just copy the important code for Datepicker

**views.py**

```
def registrarpaciente(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = PacienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mydate = form.cleaned_data('data_input') #I have agree this codeline just recently by looking another questions
            form.save()

            return render_to_response('ABME/Notificaciones/pregistrado.html')
    else:
        form = PacienteForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('ABME/Paciente/registrarpaciente.html', args)
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from aplicacion.models import *
from functools import partial

DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})

class PersonaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        exclude=()

class PacienteForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Paciente
        data_input = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
        exclude=()
```

I dont know if im not calling properly the widget or something, the scripts are called, i have already checked in the firebug so thats not the problem.. plz help!

Comment: is the `data_input` attribute really supposed to be under `Meta` class or you want it to appear as a form field instead?

Comment: I just want the form field as a calendar, i have put it there cause i dont know what else do... just seeing anothers questions..
My field where i have to put my date is called "nacimiento" (its in the html code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI " $("#datepicker").datepicker is not a function"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function)

Comment: If you have a field named `nacimiento`, all you have to do is assign a class named datepicker to that input element. it'll solve the problem.

Comment: a class in the input? .. it keeps the same problem, datepicker is not a function...
probably its missing an script or css?

Comment: Are the JS files/ resources properly loaded in DOM? have you tried switching to latest version of libraries?

Comment: whats DOM??? i have downloaded recently so i suppose i have the latest

Comment: Replace `$('.datepicker').datepicker();` with `$('#datepicker').datepicker();` because you have assigned id to input but in JS you  are using class attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the benefit of anyone else seeking an answer.

If you just need a basic datepicker and not keen on js or jquery, try the `DateInput` widget provided by `django.forms`. Here is a sample code.

```
from django.forms import Form, ModelForm, DateField, widgets
from your.models import Packaging, Purchase, Sale


class AddSaleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {
            'order_date': widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        }
```

An example using pure `Form`

```
class ReportForm(Form):
    from_date = DateField(label="From Date", widget=widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    to_date = DateField(label="To Date", widget=widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

**P.S** You would want to make sure views and templates are setup correctly. This is a code example that works with `bootstrap` and `django.views`.

Answer (score 1):

If your data_input field is a model field, use this:

```
class PacienteForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Paciente
        exclude=()  
        widgets = {
            'data_input': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'id': 'data_input'})
        }
```

If it is not a model field, then use:

```
class PacienteForm(forms.ModelForm):    
     data_input = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
     class Meta:
         model = Paciente
         exclude=()
```

Answer (score 0):

It possible the file not exist.

[image]

try this.

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
```

And the file need permissions

Comment: thats not the problem.. it keeps giving me this error : "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function"

Comment: thats not the problem i think..  i have already checked in the firebug and the scripts and the css are called, i can get inside them.

Comment: I generate the error (answer image) deleting the file

Comment: i have solve it guys! the problem was that my version of datepicker was the recently, i downloaded another and it runssssssssss :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this in you html:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap DateTime Picker Instead and specify this format. Check the code below.

```
$('id/class name').datetimepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),
            locale: 'en',
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        });
```