# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function - Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datepicker

Frustrating error. i could not readily discern an answer from stack overflow hence resorting to posting a question. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I"m getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

1. Rails 4.2.4
2. ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]

Gemfile:

```
gem 'ransack'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.14.30'
```

My application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require_tree .
```

My application.css.sass file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker'
```

This is how I am selecting my date picker (within document ready):

```
$('#date-form-control1').datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
```

This is my form:

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :invoice_invoice_date_gteq, "Date: Greater than:" %>
    <%= f.text_field  :invoice_invoice_date_gteq, id: "date-form-control1", placeholder: "Date >= to" %>
  </div>
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: is there any javascript error in the console when you load the page ? Before Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function.
It looks the date picker js library is not loaded

Comment: that is the javascript error - the page looks fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4313112/4758119

Comment: I suspect @Deepak meant to suggest the link he posted may answer to your question. Yes?

Comment: @Tass yes its similar issue

Answer (score 0):

you can't call datetimepicker with `datepicker({mindate})`

use `$('#date-form-control1').datetimepicker();`

if you only want to use date then use datepicker

Answer (score 0):

if you wants to use datepicker only than use datepiker.js javascript, because you can not use datepicker function with datetimepicker.js

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#date-form-control1" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
  } );
  </script>
```