# jQueryUI not working (in Prestashop) how to troubleshoot?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am building a Module for Prestashop that has a Front Office Controller.
I'm wanting to use jQueryUI.

In my main php file for the module (extending the Module class) in included JQueryUI like this:

```
    public function hookHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->addJqueryUI('ui.core');
    $this->context->controller->addJqueryUI('ui.widget');
    $this->context->controller->addJqueryUI('ui.mouse');
    $this->context->controller->addJqueryUI('ui.slider');
}
```

I am checking my header, and I see all the scripts are being included in the correct order. (See image) jQuery all by itself works fine. But as soon as I'm calling a jQueryUI method, it says the method is not defined.

I'm just trying to get the [basic example](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/) to work, two different ways, both don't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#date" ).datepicker();
});
```

and this doesn't work either:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker();
} );
```

it keeps saying `$(...).datepicker is not a function`.

It doesn't look like jQuery is [included twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function), since it works fine when I don't call any of the UI methods. There's just this "migration" thing, but if I rename the file so it can't be included it throws a whole host of different errors (other functions it suddenly finds undefined).

Also I've already disabled all modules but mine. Same problem.

Interestingly enough

```
window.onload = function() {
   if (typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined') {  
        alert("jquery ui is loaded!");
    } else {
        alert("not working");
    }
}
```

this says it's loaded!

**What could possibly be wrong?**

**How do I troubeshoot this?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is specify to load datepicker.

```
$this->context->controller->addJqueryUI('ui.datepicker');
```

jQuery UI in Prestashop comes with separate files for each UI component. So you need to specify which component to load.

Have a look in folder [/js/jquery/ui](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.6.1.x/js/jquery/ui) and you will see which components are available.

There is no need to specify `ui.core, ui.mouse` etc. (unless you specifically need them only) because they are dependencies of components so they get auto loaded unless you add third parameter in `addJqueryUI` method to `false`.

Dependencies for each component are defined in [Media](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Media.php#L29) class.

Example of [dialog](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Media.php#L41) component's dependencies that are automatically loaded:

```
'ui.dialog' => array('fileName' => 'jquery.ui.dialog.min.js', 'dependencies' => array('ui.core', 'ui.widget', 'ui.position','ui.button'), 'theme' => true),
```

Comment: Wow... Got it thanks! Additional question though: So if I want "dialog" which by default is "dragable" and "resizable", do I need to include all those 3 libraries?

Answer (score 1):

For now it's fixed by using the hosted libraries from Google:

```
$this->context->controller->addCSS('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
$this->context->controller->addJS('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js');
```

I have a feeling though it'll break once I include the other modules again.