# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What wrong in my code? I can't find my false.. in this jquery I have a value range, but if I send value to controller start and end date is null ??

[this error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywCyy.jpg)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
{{-- compiled js --}}
<!--<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-1.12.4.js') }}"></script>!-->
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jQuery-dataTables-Material.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

this is my code jQuery in view blade

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var start = moment('<?php echo $start; ?>','DDMMYYYY');
        var end = moment('<?php echo $end; ?>','DDMMYYYY');

        function cb(start, end) {
        alert(start);

            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

            $('body').append($('<form/>')
              .attr({'action': './invoiceList', 'method': 'post', 'id': 'replacer'})
              .append($('<input/>')
                .attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'start', 'value': start.format('DDMMYYYY')})
              )
              .append($('<input/>')
                .attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'end', 'value': end.format('DDMMYYYY')})
              )
            ).find('#replacer').submit();
        }

        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
               'Today': [moment(), moment()],
               'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
               'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
               'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
               'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
               'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, cb);

        //cb(start, end);
    });

    $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        console.log('start: '+picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        console.log('end  : '+picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        days = (moment(picker.endDate)-moment(picker.startDate))/ 1000/60/60/24;
        console.log('Range : '+Math.round(days)+' days' );
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#invoice').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

this is my code to range date.

Comment: Have you included jquery library? 'Cause I see it commented in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI " $("#datepicker").datepicker is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @ReSedano i put in the layout
 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/plugins.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI Iwill check again

Comment: ok please try atleast

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI i inspect and open network to check my jquery :

moment.min.js 
daterangepicker.js 
jquery.min.js 
bootstrap.min.js 
plugins.js 
main.js 
emojione.min.js 
jquery.dataTables.min.js 
jQuery-dataTables-Material.js 
default?refresh=true&v=582 
emojione.min.js

can u help me what wrong?

Comment: @Rani You have to reproduce that error in a jsfiddle or code snippet 'cause you are a lot of relative path or php variables and we can not reproduce your error with that code you posted.

Comment: Another check: are you working with Laravel? Sometimes its debugbar cause me some js troubles. You could disable it and see if it gives you the same error. But without a working jsfiddle they are just hypotheses.

Comment: @ReSedano i try in jsfiddle..  daterangepicker its work, but in my laravel not work

Comment: So try to check every js file Laravel automatically import in your layout. As I said sometimes the debug bar 'cause me js troubles, for example.