# JS code works in a website but getting datepicker is not a function error in another website

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I'm using js code in webview but i'm getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
                            imported.onload = function(){

                            html2canvas(document.querySelector("body > div.container-fluid > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > form > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > img"), {
                                        onrendered: function(canvas) {
                            var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
                            var w=canvas.width;
                            var h=canvas.height;
                              ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
                                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
                              var cap =document.querySelector("body > div.container-fluid > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > form > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > img")
                              ctx.drawImage(cap,0,0);
                             var imgData=canvas.toDataURL('image/webp',1.0);
                            console.log(imgData);
                                           },
                                                   allowTaint: true,
                          taintTest: false
                                    });
                            }
                            imported.src = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/dRap1YD8';
                            document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

using it on [this website](http://oous.rnu.tn/PackOffice/esp_etud/result_b.php) to get the captcha image as dataUrl

The code working fine in another website but not in [this one](http://oous.rnu.tn/PackOffice/esp_etud/result_b.php)

*NOTE: Pastebin is just temporary*

*Another Question: is this code contain jquery ?*

Comment: On your both examples you have an error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Thank you for your reply, sorry didn't understand what you mean by examples, do you mean the both websites ?

Comment: using it on this website to get the captcha image as dataUrl

The code working fine in another website but not in this one

NOTE: Pastebin is just temporary

Comment: the code working in a website but not in this website i posted in the question
i think something about using jquery twice

Comment: This problem occur usually at the time when you load your library early or without needed component.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco what library ? i'm not the owner of the website btw

Comment: i mean the order how you load the jquery and bootstrap libraries. that is the issue.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco in android code, i use a webview so i run the js code after the website fully loaded using `onPageFinished ` so everything loaded correctly

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function?rq=1