# Uncaught TypeError datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am having issues adding a Jquery datepicker to the existing html screen. The datepicker isn't recognised as a function in my JS file. I have gone through the some proposed solutions in this page but no luck yet, Not sure where the actual problem is why the function isn't recognised.

Part of Html code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link th:replace="fragments/structure/favicon" />
    <meta th:replace="fragments/structure/meta_tags" />
    <link th:replace="fragments/structure/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
Date Picker on input field: <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1"/> <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Part of javaScript Code

```
viewDate = function () {
                alert('Test function');  //The calls comes here
                $('#date1').datepicker({ //At this point it says Undefined
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    dateFormat: "m/d/yy"
                });
            },
```

This is what I see in Debug 'Elements' after html page loaded, As the jquery is already inherited from a different js I didn't add it explicitly to the html to avoid duplication

[image: test]

JavaScript file included in the html file

[image]

What am I missing here? Appreciate your help. Thanks

**Update - Fix works but with an impact**

Solution from freedomn-m works. Moving the jquery-ui to the end of the page solved the issue on fund-cards.js. But this impacts an other JS file (invesco-fund-cards.js) which is included in the same HTML file. The page is not loading up throwing Uncaught TypeError: $(...) on is not a function

Now, If I remove line number 181 (jquery.min.js) the invesco-fund-cards.js works fine but fund-cards.js fails!

I must mention that jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js is globally injected into the html file when the page loads up.

Any idea how to handle this tricky situation? Appreciate your help

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435294/1832954 ?

Comment: From the code/screenshots, you're trying to load jquery-ui *before* jquery.js.  It must be after.

Comment: Always check the browser console for all errors in order: `jquery-ui.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` which occurs before *datepicker is not a function*

Comment: @freedomn-m - Moving the jquery-ui to the end of the page solved the issue. Thanks a mil. But this impacts an other JS file which is included on the same HTML file. I will try to explain it with screenshots

Comment: *Edit* to fix formatting: Solution: move the `<script src=jquery-iu` to the end just before `</body>`.  Though I can't see where you call `viewDate()`` so make sure it's before that - or add doc.ready around the call to viewDate and/or inside.

Comment: The simplest option is to ensure all your scripts are loaded in the same place, then you can determine their order.  If you have a *random* extra jquery injected by some component, then that'll likely break your site in general and you should probably fix that!

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks a mil for your help. It worked